# Look for file in directory that contains a certain substring

Tags: c#, xml, autocad

I'm attempting to loop through a specific directory until I find a file containing a certain substring. The file in question is an XML file used for parameter communication between Python and an Autocad C# Plugin.

**Here's what I've completed so far.**

1. Create an XML file containing the required parameters in Python.
2. Save that file as `xrefTester_(currentDateTime).xml` in `C:\Temp\`

   **Here's what I still need to complete:**
3. Use an infinite loop in C# to find the created XML file.
4. Once the file is found add `.bak` to the end of it so my loop knows to pass it over in the future (this is because multiple XML files containing the substring `xref_tester` will exist in `C:\Temp\`

I have the infinite loop set up and I have no problem getting the files in the directory. However I'm having trouble asserting that a file containing `xrefTester` and not ending in `.bak` exists.

Comment: Can you _show us_ the code that is giving you problems? It's easier to post your code instead of only describing it.

Comment: @gunr2171 I just updated my question. I feel it was a little unclear. I have the infinite loop and I have an array containing all the files in the directory. However I'm struggling with the if statement and subsequent break.

Comment: Well, first, you don't have a question mark in your post anywhere. But you are saying you have problems with your code. Ok, _show it_. Let us help you fix your code by first letting us see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you have tried or where you've been stuck, but i would use something like this:

```
var xmlFiles = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*.xml")
               let fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
               where fileName.StartsWith("xrefTester_(") && !fileName.EndsWith(".bak")
               select file;
foreach(string path in xmlFiles)
{
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),
                ".bak",
                Path.GetExtension(path));
    File.Move(path, Path.Combine(dir, newFileName)); // cannot exist due to logic above
}
```